# Kotlin dynamic number of parameters in function?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to write a single function that takes a dynamic closure/function

```
router.intercept("users/:userId") { (userId: Int) ->
   print("User id is $userId")
}

router.intercept("users/:userId/albums/:albumName") { (userId: Int, albumName: String) ->
   print("User id is $usrrId, album is $albumName")
}
```

With swift this is possible by using named tuples, is it possible to achieve this with kotlin?

- I want variables to be named
- I want to be able to support `n` number of parameters

Comment: have a look at vararg https://medium.com/@agrawalsuneet/variable-number-of-arguments-vararg-kotlin-f1c25b79de14 . I am not sure if that's what you need

Comment: varargs can't be named, also can't be different types

Comment: yes they cannot be named but  you can take `Any` if you want different types

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to overload `intercept` n-times generically and infer the type with the lambda definition:

```
fun <T1> intercept(path: String, cb: (T1) -> Unit) = ...
fun <T1, T2> intercept(path: String, cb: (T1, T2) -> Unit) = ...
fun <T1, T2, T3> intercept(path: String, cb: (T1, T2, T3) -> Unit) = ...

router.intercept("users/:userId/albums/:albumName") { userId: Int, albumName: String -> }
```

But for `intercept` all parameters will look like `Any?` and you might not get any information about the name or type you declared with the lambda and using a wrong type for it will result in exceptions.

To use *Kotlin* to its full extend, you could make it all type-safe with [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) and [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html):

```
sealed class Route
data class UsersRoute(
    val userId: Int,
    val albumName: String
) : Route()

fun <R: Route> intercept(path: String, cb: (R) -> Unit) = ...

router.intercept("users/:userId") { (userId): UsersRoute -> }
router.intercept<UsersRoute>("users/:userId/albums/:albumName") { (userId, albumName) -> }
```

If you only have  the *users* route, you don't even need the generic and sealed class approach.